# What can be proved about parameters in lambda expressions, passed into monads?

Tags: haskell, monads

Relative to the fish operator, Monads satisfy associativity.

```
(h >=> g) >=> f = h >=> ( g >=> f)
```

This translated to bind (with lambda expressions) looks like,

```
\a -> h a >>=(\b -> g b >>= \c -> f c) = 
\a ->(h a >>= \b -> g b)>>= \c -> f c
```

which means the following equation is unambiguous

```
( a -> h a >>= \b -> g b >>= \c -> f c ) =  h >=> g >=> f
```

This is a nice way to understand Monadic composition.

However not all Monadic code keeps the bound variables to the lambdas separated. For example,

```
[1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch) = 
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]
```

The "n" in the return was obtained from the top lambda.

More generally,

```
a -> g a >>= \b -> f a b
```

f depends on both a and b in the above. Defining the above in terms of f, g, and (>=>) gives

```
\a -> (\x -> g a) >=> f a
```

Which I don't understand very well. It doesn't match the above equation I showed very well. I see fish as the fundamental notion here, and I'm trying to understand how it interacts with typical Monads I write. I would like to understand the above better.

One way of approaching this is by trying to obtain meaning from List expression syntax

```
[ (n,ch) | n <- [1, 2], ch <- ['a', 'b'] ]
```

I think this implies a kind of symmetry.

Are there any nice symmetries connecting lambda expressions and Monads? Or am I reading too much into this? Is my fear of highly nested lambda expressions wrong or reasonable?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.

Comment: "Intuitively, I'm afraid of subtle coupling between the nested lambdas." -- Could you say a bit more on what you are worried with?

Comment: @duplode Does my edit clarify my worry?

Comment: It does; I added an answer which focuses on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there aren't any restrictions. Once you've bound a lambda you can do [anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). This is one of the reasons of `Applicative` being preferrable to `Monad` *because it's weaker* (and hence gives you stronger free-theorem restrictions).

```
 ( [1,2] >>= \n -> "ab" >>= \ch -> return (n,ch) )
   ≡  (,) <$> [1,2] <*> "ab"
   ≡  liftA2 (,) [1,2] "ab"
   ≈  liftA2 (flip (,)) "ab" [1,2]
```

The last is actually not a proper equation; the applicative laws only <del>guarantee that the *values* will be the same for these expressions</del><sup>See comments</sup>, but the *structure* can and will be different.

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> liftA2 (,) [1,2] "ab"
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]
Prelude Control.Applicative> liftA2 (flip (,)) "ab" [1,2]
[(1,'a'),(2,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'b')]
```

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure quite what relation between `f <$> x <*> y` and `flip f <$> y <*> x` the applicative laws imply; I'm pretty sure they say _something_ about that symmetry but I've always had trouble properly understanding those laws.

Comment: Regarding your comment: `State` is a counterexample of the sameness of values between `f <$> x <*> y` and `flip f <$> y <*> x` -- for instance, `runState ((/) <$> state ((2*) &&& (3*)) <*> state ((+4) &&& (subtract 3))) 1` is `(1/7, 0)`, but `runState (flip (/) <$> state ((+4) &&& (subtract 3)) <*> state ((2*) &&& (3*))) 1` is `(-4/5, -6)`.

Comment: More generally, the `Applicative` interface does not itself enable dependence between effects, but its existence does not prevent such dependence either. I think `StateT` may get at this even better than `State`, as it allows practically arbitrary dependence.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing your edit, in which you consider how to write...

> ```
> \a -> g a >>= \b -> f a b
> ```

... using `(>=>)`, nothing is actually lost in that case. It is helpful to take a step back and consider exactly how `(>=>)` can be converted into `(>>=)` and vice-versa:

```
f >=> g = \x -> f x >>= g
m >>= f = (const m >=> f) () -- const x = \_ -> x
```

In the second equation, which is the one related to your concerns, we turn the first argument to `(>>=)` into a function which can be passed to `(>=>)` by using `const`. As `const m >=> f` is a functions which ignores its argument, we just pass `()` as a dummy argument in order to recover `(>>=)`.

That being so, your example can be rewritten by using the second equation:

```
\a -> g a >>= \b -> f a b
\a -> (const (g a) >=> \b -> f a b) ()
\a -> (const (g a) >=> f a) ()
```

Which, except for the added trick of supplying a dummy `()`, is what you had obtained in your question.

Answer (score 2):

An additional idea to your question: Monads are most general in the sense that effects can depend on inputs. A monadic computation `m` that takes input `a` and produces output `b` can be written as `a -> m b`. As this is a function, we (can) define such computations using lambdas, which can naturally span fo the right. But this generality complicates analyzing computations as your `\a -> g a >>= \b -> f a b`.

For [arrows](https://www.haskell.org/arrows/) (which occupy the space between applicative functors and monads) the situation is somewhat different. For a general arrow, the input must be explicit - an arrow computation `arr` has the general type of `arr a b`. And so an input that spans "forward" in an arrow computation must be explicitly threaded there using Arrow primitives.

To expand your example

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

import Control.Arrow

bind2 :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> (a -> b -> m c) -> a -> m c
bind2 g f = \a -> g a >>= \b -> f a b
```

to arrows: Function `f` must now take a pair as its input (because arrows are defined as accepting one input value). Using the arrow `do` notation we can express it as

```
bind2A :: (Arrow arr) => arr a b -> arr (a, b) c -> arr a c
bind2A g f = proc a -> do
                b <- g -< a
                c <- f -< (a, b)
                returnA -< c
```

Or even simpler using the `Arrow` primitives:

```
bind2A' :: (Arrow arr) => arr a b -> arr (a, b) c -> arr a c
bind2A' g f = (returnA &&& g) >>> f
```

Graphically:

```
--------------->[   ]
   \            [ f ]---->
    \-->[ g ]-->[   ]
```

Being less general, arrows allow to infer more information about a circuit before it's actually executed. A nice reading is [Understanding arrows](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows), which describes the original motivation behind them - to construct parsers that can can avoid space leaks by having static and dynamic parts.